# IntelliJ cannot resolve taglib for the neighbouring dir in the same module

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, module, taglib

A jsp file has a line:

```
<%@ taglib uri="../../WEB-INF/thincore.tld" prefix="TL" %>
```

And the address in it is red and gives a hint: "cannot resolve taglib ../../WEB-INF/thincore.tld".
But the file really lies in the "uncle" directory, in the same module, both jsp file and its uncle lie in the same grandfather, marked as a source dir. So, I don't know about any logical border between them.

### It is not a duplicate!

I have read all questions on SO with the same "**IntelliJ cannot resolve taglib**" in the title, but they all are about seeing some distant libraries, that really must be registered. But registering the module in itself seems senseless to me.

I am not expecting the answer (I would be grateful, though), but at least some hint where to investigate.

### It seems that the module is invisible for itself?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the source of the problem.

The fact the grandfather folder is the source folder does not mean that its folders will be considered as library folders, and their files, being `lib`s/`jar`s/`tld`s and not java files, are simply not seen when they are needed. So, yes, **we must set in the Project Structure the appropriate folder as a library, even if it is inside the module**.